# How to label pandas rows by values within some bin size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label

I have the following pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df

    column1     column2    column3
0   52767       10         AA
1   52981       15         AA
2   53479       19         BB
3   53891       5071       BB 
4   54012       5891       BB
5   54231       3210       BB
6   54421       12         BB
7   54789       13         CC
8   55011       20         CC
...
```

I would like to uniquely label each rows of this DataFrame based on whether the value of `column2` falls within a certain value. Let's say I would like to label all unique "bunches" of rows when the value of `column2` is less than or equal to 19. We'll put these labels in the column `groupings`

Then the resulting dataframe would be

```
    column1     column2    column3    groupings
0   52767       10         AA         1
1   52981       15         AA         1
2   53479       19         BB         1
3   53891       5071       BB         0
4   54012       5891       BB         0
5   54231       3210       BB         0
6   54421       12         BB         2
7   54789       13         CC         2
8   55011       20         CC         0
...
```

Here there are two unique groups of rows where the value of `column2` is <=19. Rows 0, 1, and 2 in this example are a "bunch" of rows, i.e. a consecutive grouping of rows such that the values of column2 are <=19.

Somehow, one should also be able to use `groupby()` to repeat this analysis, but taking into account that one should not count rows between categories in `column3`. This dataframe would look like

```
    column1     column2    column3    groupings
0   52767       10         AA         1
1   52981       15         AA         1
2   53479       19         BB         0   # not a bunch, only one row <= 19 in BB
3   53891       5071       BB         0
4   54012       5891       BB         0
5   54231       3210       BB         0
6   54421       12         BB         0   # not a bunch, only one row <= 19 in BB, not two consecutive
7   54789       13         CC         0
8   55011       20         CC         0
9   55347       5          CC         2   # here there are two rows consecutively <= 19
10  55789       9          CC         2  
...
```

I'm entirely stuck how to accomplish this task in pandas. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your `groupings` column does not have unique values. What exactly do you mean by "uniquely label each row"? As for the possible solution to your problem, you may want to look at `pandas.cut()`.

Comment: @DYZ What I mean by "uniquely" is that the number of rows matching this condition. Rows 0, 1, and 2 in the first example each are a "bunch" of rows, i.e. a consecutive grouping of rows such that the values of column2 are <=19. Does this make sense? I'll edit for clarity

Comment: I think you need to remove the word 'uniquely', because surely it sends the wrong message. And yes, you need `pandas.cut()`.

Comment: @DYZ So, the bin size for `pandas.cut()` is specified for each row whether `column2` is of the value `<=19`?

Comment: Correct, as in `pd.cut(df.column2, [-np.inf,19,np.inf], labels=(1,0))`. But unfortunately all rows below 19 would be labeled with the same label. You'll need some other tool to relabel them with sequential numbers.

Comment: @DYZ Using pandas.cut(), how does one take into account the groupings column? I don't think one can do `pd.cut(df.groupby("groupings").column2, [-np.inf,19,np.inf], labels=(1,0))` really

Comment: At the moment, you don't do grouping, you do classification: `df['groupings"]=pd.cut(df.column2, [-np.inf,19,np.inf], labels=(1,0))`. You do grouping later if you want.

Comment: Those are the bin boundaries. If you plan to use `cut`, you should read its documentation.

Comment: @DYZ Sorry, yes, the bin boundaries are defined in the documentation. Sorry, I think I was confusing in my previous response. I meant to type `pd.cut(df.groupby("column3").column2, [-np.inf,19,np.inf], labels=(1,0))`. This is the second example above, where row 2 is not in the first group, as it was `column3` value `BB`

Comment: Here's the corrected comment from previous (sorry again): Using `pandas.cut()`, how does one take into account the column `column3`? I don't think one can do `pd.cut(df.groupby("column3").column2, [-np.inf,19,np.inf], labels=(1,0))` really

Comment: So, we bin the data on `df.column2`, somehow(?) grouped by the categories of `df.column3`. Does it make sense what I am asking? (Also, please comment below so I can give you points....this has been a very good learning experience.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's a complete procedure for you:

First, generate a column that marks the rows in a bunch (adjust the threshold, `19`, if needed):

```
df["groupings"] = pd.cut(df.column2, [-np.inf, 19, np.inf], labels=(1,0))
```

The column consists of 0's and 1's, but you want 0's and bunch numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.), so let's renumber the bunches:

```
df.groupings = (df[df.groupings==1].index.to_series().diff() > 1).cumsum() + 1
df['groupings'] = df['groupings'].fillna(0).astype(int) # Remove nans
```

This concludes the answer to your first question:

```
#    column2 column3  groupings
#0        10       A          1
#1        15       A          1
#2        19       B          1
#3      5071       B          0
#4      5891       B          0
#5      3210       B          0
#6        12       B          2
#7        13       C          2
#8        20       C          0
#9         5       C          3
#10        9       C          3
```

However, some marked rows shall be removed. Let's find out, which:

```
bunches = df.groupby('groupings').apply(lambda x:
                                        x['column3'].value_counts() <=1 ).reset_index()
bunches.columns=('groupings','column3','weed')

#   groupings column3   weed
#0          0       B  False
#1          0       C   True
#2          1       A  False
#3          1       B   True
#4          2       C   True
#5          2       B   True
#6          3       C  False
```

This dataframe has all rows in all bunches and also marks the "weed" rows.  We need to know who are the "weeds":

```
weeds = bunches[(bunches.weed) & (bunches.groupings > 0)]
#   groupings column3  weed
#3          1       B  True
#4          2       C  True
#5          2       B  True
```

Let's combine this information with the original dataframe:

```
merged = df.merge(weeds, on=['groupings','column3'], how='outer')    
#    column2 column3  groupings  weed
#0        10       A          1   NaN
#1        15       A          1   NaN
#2        19       B          1  True
#3      5071       B          0   NaN
#4      5891       B          0   NaN
#5      3210       B          0   NaN
#6        12       B          2  True
#7        13       C          2  True
#8        20       C          0   NaN
#9         5       C          3   NaN
#10        9       C          3   NaN
```

Note that the "weed" rows are marked as such! Let's finally unmark them as belonging to bunches:

```
df.loc[merged[merged.weed==True].index, 'groupings']=0
#    column2 column3  groupings
#0        10       A          1
#1        15       A          1
#2        19       B          0
#3      5071       B          0
#4      5891       B          0
#5      3210       B          0
#6        12       B          0
#7        13       C          0
#8        20       C          0
#9         5       C          3
#10        9       C          3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a list to store the data
groupings = []

# For each row in the column,
for row in df['column2']:
    # if more than a value,
    if row < 20:
        # Append a letter grade
        groupings.append('1')
    else: 
        groupings.append('0')
```

For the second part I am not sure...